# What is the proper way to watch and reload Nginx conf?

Tags: nginx

I have two questions:

- Is there a difference between: `nginx -s reload` and `pkill -HUP -F nginx.pid`
- What is the proper way to watch the Nginx conf file and upon changes test the conf file (`nginx -t`), and if it passes reload Nginx. Can that be done with `runit` or a process manager like Supervisor?

Comment: What specific GNU/Linux distro is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nginx -s reload` also sends a `HUP` signal as per the man pages.

Refer to [Nginx Man Pages](http://www.rootr.net/man/man/nginx/8)

For the second part. It is possible monitor the nginx.conf file for changes and trigger a test and reload on change. I use a bash script and run it every 15 seconds using [supervise](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html). Monitor the `mtime` of the config file and upon change run `nginx -t` which will return  `exit code 0` upon successful verification of config file, then reload.

Comment: If it is GNU/Linux, you can use inotify or on FreeBSd you can use kqueue/kevent to monitor a file (windows has IO completion ports). The mtime approach can be faked via setattr to reset the mtime but should suffice for simple needs and it is based on polling.

Comment: is this better than using `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` ?